Proof strategies for non-hardness in a class alternative to membership in a lower class
Suppose I have a problem $P$ that belongs to $k$-EXPTIME for some $k$, but is not yet known whether it is $k$-EXPTIME-hard or not.
Suppose I'm convinced it is not $k$-EXPTIME-hard.
Conceptually I could take a $k$-EXPTIME-complete problem $P'$ and prove that a polynomial-time reduction from $P'$ to $P$ does not exist. Is there any other proof strategy to attack this other than proving $P$'s membership in a provably smaller class?
One thing may be necessary conditions for such reductions to exist. Or some way to compose a diagonalization argument to lead to a contradiction.
Any pointer in the literature is welcome.
